# How to choose grid search (when working with trainer.hyperparameter_search)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I want to run `trainer.hyperparameter_search` (with **grid search**) and I haven't seen any HP algorithm type parameter.

How can I configure `trainer.hyperparameter_search` to run with grid-search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Optuna for this:

```
def hp_search(trial):
    return {
        "learning_rate": trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 5e-5, 5e-6, log=True),
        "num_train_epochs": trial.suggest_int("num_train_epochs", 3,10),
        "per_device_train_batch_size": trial.suggest_categorical("per_device_train_batch_size", [1,2,4,6,8,16,32]),
    }

trainer.hyperparameter_search(direction="maximize", hp_space=hp_space)
```

This [thread](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/using-hyperparameter-search-in-trainer/785/55?page=3) should also bring more light to the task at hand.